# No implementation of method: :spec of protocol: #'schema.core/Schema

Tags: clojure

I've written a macro

```
(defmacro defendpoint [msg-type url-key schema]
  `(defrecord ~msg-type []
     Create
     (create [entity#]
       (s/validate ~schema entity#)
       (create-entity (~url-key urls) entity#))))
```

and I'm using it like so

```
(defendpoint Location :locations
  {... my schema ...}})

(defendpoint LocationHierarchy :location-hierarchies
  {... my schema ...}})
```

The first time I use the macro, it works

```
(create  (map->Location
          {... data ...}))

=> { ... json response ...}
```

But the second time, it fails:

```
(create  (map->LocationHierarchy
          {... data ...}))

=> 1. Unhandled java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 No implementation of method: :spec of protocol:
 #'schema.core/Schema found for class: ohds.client$fn__32303
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. I expect that the second call will work in the same way as the first, but it seems like there is an error in the validation step. In fact, if I remove `(s/validate...)` from the macro, it works as expected. So I'm not sure exactly what's going on here.

[I've created a gist that shows the entire file I'm working with](https://gist.github.com/munk/a333e4d64e3de2d146d2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to go through how I solved my problem in hopes that the method helps somebody else.

**tl;dr**

```
;; Wrong:
(def date-schema (s/both s/Str #(re-matches #"my-regex" %)))
;; Right:
(def date-schema (s/both s/Str (s/pred #(re-matches #"my-regex" %))))
```

**The Method**

I started with the error: `No implementation of method: :spec of protocol:
 #'schema.core/Schema found for class: ohds.client$fn__32303`

I wasn't sure what this meant at first. `:spec of protocol:` threw me off. But I did see it was mentioning `schema.core/Schema`, so I read [the source code](https://github.com/plumatic/schema/blob/master/src/cljx/schema/core.cljx#L109). I discovered Schema was a protocol with a method `spec`, just like the error says :/

The next part that was confusing was `for class: ohds.client$fn__32303`. I was wondering why my namespace needed to implement the protocol. That didn't make any sense. Then I noticed `$fn_32303`. This told me there was a lambda somewhere where the mistake was!

At this point, it was my hypothesis that my schema had a problem. So I removed all the special validation from my schema and used `s/Str` everywhere to see if it worked. It did, so I was in the right spot! I added the special validation back, one at a time, until the test failed again. The problem was in my date-schema.

I looked at the schema I defined just above it to see what was different. There I noticed I'd failed to to wrap my lambda in `s/pred`.

**The Moral**

Clojure is well designed, so the error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. You just need to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this happen to me. Turned out i had a `defschema` that was referencing itself:

```
(s/defschema Templates {:templates [Templates]
                        :error     s/Bool})
```

instead of the correct reference:

```
(s/defschema Templates {:templates [Template]
                        :error     s/Bool})
```